# Proof that a matrix can be written as the product of a positive definite matrix and an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I show that for a real invertible matrix $A$ with dimensions $n \times  n$

$A$ can be written:

$A = B C$
where $B$ is a positive definite matrix and $C$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 6):

This is called the (left) polar decomposition of $A$. Note that if $A = BC$ where $B$ is positive definite and $C$ is orthogonal then

$$ A^T A = (BC)^T (BC) = C^T B^T B C = C^T C = C^2. $$

This means that you have $C = \sqrt{A^T A}$ (where $\sqrt{A^T A}$ is the unique positive definite root of $A^T A$) and $B = AC^{-1} = A(\sqrt{A^T A})^{-1}$. Going backwards, in order to show that such a decomposition exist define

$$ C := \sqrt{A^T A}, \,\,\, B := A(\sqrt{A^T A})^{-1} $$

and show that this is indeed well-defined, that $B$ is orthogonal and that $C$ is positive definite and that $A = BC$.

Comment: How can I prove that this is well defined? I can do it assuming another factorization, that is, assuming that $A=B'C'$ and getting to that $B=B'$ and $C=C'$? On the other hand, to prove that $B$ is orthogonal, could do the following: $$BB^T=\sqrt{A^TA}(\sqrt{A^TA})^T=\sqrt{A^TA}\sqrt{(A^TA)^T}=\sqrt{A^TA}\sqrt{A^TA}=\sqrt{A^TAA^TA}=Id$$? I don't know how to prove that $C$ is positively defined, any help to do this? Thank you!

Comment: @Nash: Well, the first thing you need to know is that $A^TA$ is positive definite. It is clearly symmetric and $\left< A^TAv, v \right> = \left< Av, Av \right> > 0$ if $v \neq 0$ (since $A$ is invertible). Then you need to know that for any positive definite matrix $P$ there is a unique positive definite matrix $C$ such that $C^2 = P$ which is denoted by $\sqrt{P}$. Hence, $C$ is positive definite. Then you need to compute $BB^T$ and show that you get $I$.

Comment: @Nash: Your calculation is not correct as for some reason you forgot the $A$ factor of $B$. The calculation is not entirely trivial as you need to know that $\sqrt{A^T A}$ commutes with $A,A^T$. Open any decent book in linear algebra that talks about polar decomposition to see a full proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $A=USV^T$ is an SVD of $A$, then $A=(USU^T)(UV^T)=:BC$. Since $A$ is invertible, $S$ is diagonal invertible as well with positive diagonal entries, hence $B=USU^T$ is positive definite. The matrix $C=UV^T$ is a product of two orthogonal matrices and so is orthogonal.